# Flutter dismiss item in Animated List not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, animation, flutter-animatedlist

I am using `AnimatedList` in my Flutter app. It is working, but the `dismiss`-behavior is not smooth because the dismissed item changes to its above item while transitioning.

[Here](https://gofile.io/d/RJ8iju) is a Screenvideo for a better understanding. Concentrate on the text, it always changes mid-transition to the text of the first item ("Hallo Das ist 1").

I followed this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-animate-items-in-list-using-animatedlist-in-flutter-9b1a64e9aa16) where you can also test it on a CodePad where you can see the exact same behavior. This is not the desired animation... Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is how I dismiss the items:

```
 _removeMemoryAtIndex(int index, Month currentMonth) {
    listKey.currentState!.removeItem(
      index,
      (_, animation) => slideIt(
        context,
        currentMonth,
        0,
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut),
      ),
      duration: Duration(
        milliseconds: 500,
      ),
    );

    Provider.of<MemoryImageProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .removeMemoryAt(index: index);
  }
```

and my `slideIt` - function for the animation:

```
Widget slideIt(
    BuildContext context,
    Month currentMonth,
    int index,
    animation,
  ) {
    Memory memory = currentMonth.memories[index];
    return SlideTransition(
      position: Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
        end: Offset(0, 0),
      ).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animation,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          MemoryTile(
            memory: memory,
            monthName: currentMonth.name,
            onTapped: () {
              _removeMemoryAtIndex(index, currentMonth);
              print('tap on ${memory.description}');
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: scaleWidth(20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you need any more info just let know! Any help is appreciated. I hope this can be fixed somehow...

Comment: maybe we can try making it async like  _removeMemoryAtIndex(int index, Month currentMonth) async{
await    listKey.currentState!.removeItem( ....

Comment: Have you set key to all the items in AnimatedList? The behaviour you are explaining might happen when Key property is not set and is not unique to every element (key should not be index but should be based on id)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh `removeItem` is not asnyc..

Answer (score 0):

we can create a temp Model Data for that, this is how it will be work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MemoryTile {
  int index;
  String name;
  MemoryTile({
    required this.index,
    required this.name,
  });
}

final items = List.generate(
  10,
  (index) => MemoryTile(
    index: index,
    name: "name $index",
  ),
);

class AnimLtest extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimLtest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimLtestState createState() => _AnimLtestState();
}

class _AnimLtestState extends State<AnimLtest> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  // Remove the selected item from the list model.

  _removeMemoryAtIndex(int index, MemoryTile currentMonth) {
    var tempMOnth = currentMonth;

    listKey.currentState!.removeItem(
      index,
      (_, animation) => slideIt(
        context,
        tempMOnth,
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut),
      ),
      duration: Duration(
        milliseconds: 500,
      ),
    );

    items.removeAt(index);
    // setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedList(
      key: listKey,
      initialItemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) => Container(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            _removeMemoryAtIndex(index, items[index]);
          },
          child: slideIt(
            context,
            items[index],
            animation,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget slideIt(
    BuildContext context,
    MemoryTile memory,
    animation,
  ) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
        end: Offset(0, 0),
      ).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
          parent: animation,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut,
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            child: Text(memory.index.toString()),
          ),
          Text("Name+> ${memory.name}")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stupid mistake... If you look at the `_removeMemoryAtIndex` method I always passed `0` as index...